# Unauthorized endpoint when calling Metadata API from Apex in @future

Tags: metadata-api, future, platform-bug, remote-site-settings, calloutexception

I am running into the exception

> IO Exception: Unauthorized endpoint, please check
>   Setup->Security->Remote site settings. endpoint =
>   https://eu25.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/42.0

when calling the Metadata API from an `@future` Apex method

```
@Future(Callout=true)
private static void updateValueSet(Set<String> newTopics, String fieldName) {
    MetadataService.MetadataPort mdapi = new MetadataService.MetadataPort();
    mdapi.SessionHeader = new MetadataService.SessionHeader_element();
    mdapi.SessionHeader.sessionId = UserInfo.getSessionId();

    ...

    mdapi.updateMetadata(new List<MetadataService.Metadata>{ fieldMdApi });
}
```

even if this should work now as I have:

1. `MetadataService` class uses `v.46` and `URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() + '/services/Soap/m/42.0'`
2. Org is on Winter '19 so `UserInfo.getSessionId()` even in `@future` should not return null.

I think with having 1. and 2. in place there is no need for a Remote Site Setting anymore. Is this a bug?

Comment: I have a hunch, it only works if you have my domain enabed, as 
`https://eu25.salesforce.com/services/Soap/m/42.0` can be for any org in EU25 pod

Comment: Very good hint. What do you think will only work with MyDomain enabled? URL.getOrgDomainUrl().toExternalForm() or UserInfo.getSessionId()? Is there a way for you to find out if this is documented anywhere?

Comment: `To bypass remote site settings, My Domain must be enabled in your org` , here's docs: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm

Comment: Can you add that as an answer and I can accept it? Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From SF Docs](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter19/release-notes/rn_apex_streamline_api_calls.htm)

> To bypass remote site settings, My Domain must be enabled in your org

The reason being, without MyDomain and using instance name we can't guarantee that we would be just calling our org because multiple orgs can be on same pod.